# script shell that browse Dir and search sub-dir with the same name in other Dir with a specified copy

Tags: shell

I have two directories : Dir1 and Dir2.
Dir1 contains several sub-directories and each directory contains several files with different name.
Dir2 contains some same sub-directories with the same name than the Dir1'sub-directories and each directory contains several files. 
I need a script shell that browse Dir1, and search for each of its subdirectory if a sub-directoy with the same name exists in Dir2, if the results is true, it copies all files except one specified file with specified extension in the correct sub-directory in Dir2.
By hoping to be clear, thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Dir1="/path/to/Dir1/"
Dir2="/path/to/Dir2/"

cd $Dir2

for DirFromDir2 in $(find . -type d)

cd $Dir1

find  $DirFromDir2 -exec cp {} $Dir2 \; 2>/dev/null

Comment: Hello, I don't know how to indicate files (specified files not all files of the subdir) of the subdirectory X of Dir 1 to copy in the subdirectory X of Dir 2?

Answer (score 0):

> … it copies all files except one specified file …

If you're using `bash`, *the GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file names* (`man bash`, **Pathname Expansion**). Example with the *specified file* being `pluto.txt`:

```
#!/bin/bash
Dir1="old" Dir2="new"
GLOBIGNORE=*/pluto.txt
for DirFromDir2 in `cd $Dir2; echo */`
do  [ -d $Dir1/$DirFromDir2 ] && cp $Dir1/$DirFromDir2* $Dir2
done
```